# HTTP to HTTPS redirection not working on AWS ALB

Tags: wordpress, amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-elb

I am using ECS for WordPress site and using Application Load Balancer (ALB) for load balancing and offloading SSL. ALB is using 2 different listeners on both port 80 and 443. The redirection rule is attached to the port 80 listener which is:

```
Redirect tohttps://#{host}:443/#{path}?#{query} 
Status code:HTTP_301
```

The webserver is nginx with php-fpm and listening on port 80. There is no redirection being done at nginx.

So, basically what I want is http (user req) -> https (ALB redirection) -> http (nginx)

Now the problem is that the ALB is not redirecting the http traffic for the main home page like

http://example.com -> http://example.com (ALB no redirection) -> http://example.com (nginx)

but it works with the same domain but different URL like:

http://example.com/page -> https://example.com/page (ALB redirection) -> http://example.com/page (nginx)

Edit:
Here is the [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YJ7Tg.jpg) to the ALB listener rules.

Comment: If it is not redirecting... then what is it doing?  Just staying on HTTP, or something else?  Is there another rule on the ALB that matches before this one (higher in the list of rules)?

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot yes it just stays on HTTP. No, there is no rule other than that on port 80. On port 443, the default action is to forward traffic to ECS cluster which is working fine.

Comment: Check your browser cache?  There's no reason for just the main page to do this unless you really do have a rule matching the path `/` or it's cached in your browser.

Comment: I have checked it on multiple browsers on incognito modes, even on mobile too, it's the same. You can check my configurations [here](https://imgur.com/a/0eLJ0BI).

Comment: hi @Usama, did you manage to fix your issue. I am facing a similar issue. `http` traffic is not getting redirected to `https`

Answer (score 10):

If the other answer doesn't work, double-check that your Security group allows inbound connections on port 80

1. Go to your load balancer
2. Click on `Description`. Scroll down to `Security Groups` to find your security group
3. Click on your Security group and check that inbound connections are allowed on port 80. If not add them. Even though you are redirecting traffic from port 80, they'll never make it to that step if they are blocked here.

[image: security group rules]

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem.
Removed the HTTP listener, added it back again, and it began to work properly.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you're doing wrong, but the port 80 listener can handle the redirect to https.

You can update the port 80 listener manually, or if you're using cloudformation it would look like:

```
Listener80:
  Type: AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::Listener
  Properties:
    DefaultActions:
      - RedirectConfig:
          Port: 443
          Protocol: HTTPS
          StatusCode: HTTP_301
        Type: redirect
    LoadBalancerArn: !Ref ALB
    Port: 80
    Protocol: HTTP
```

The listener configuration looks like:

[image: Recirect Listener - Console]

Comment: Thanks for the cloudformation template but currently I am not using it for ALB. You can check my ALB configuration [here](https://imgur.com/a/0eLJ0BI), it's same as the screenshot you shared above.